# Bash double brackets [[ with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo

I've got a command that is working when run as the current user but if I prefix `sudo` to the command, it gives me an error.

I'm trying to remove a file if it's a directory (but not if it's a symlink to a directory). This works great:

```
brad@ip-10-0-0-1:~$ [[ -d /path/to/my/place && ! -L /path/to/my/place ]] && rm -rf /path/to/my/place
```

But if I try to use `sudo` to do this as a super user I get an error because `sudo` seems to think `[[` is a command:

```
brad@ip-10-0-0-1:~$ sudo [[ -d /path/to/my/place && ! -L /path/to/my/place ]] && rm -rf /path/to/my/place
sudo: [[: command not found
```

I had to add the double brackets to get the `! -L /path/to/my/place` bit to work; `sudo` was working fine with single brackets before when I was running

```
brad@ip-10-0-0-1:~$ sudo [ -d /path/to/my/place ] && rm -rf /path/to/my/place
```

But now that I'm trying to check to ensure it's not a symlink I can't get it to work with `sudo`. How can I either:

- Get the double bracket syntax to work with `sudo` or
- Get the single bracket syntax to allow me to negate the `-L` portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
$ type -a [[
[[ is a shell keyword
$
```

As you can see `[` (beside being a shell builtin) is a regular command that `sudo` can use. `[[` is not. You need `bash` to provide `[[`:

```
sudo bash -c '[[ -d /path/to/my/place && ! -L /path/to/my/place ]]' && …
```

Because `[[` is a shell keyword, the parser recognizes it and changes the behavior of `&&` between `[[` and `]]`. You cannot use `&&` inside `[ … ]` because `[` acts as a command and `]` is in fact the last argument passed to it. Having `&&` inside means there are two commands which is wrong.

However `[` supports `-a`, so this *may* work:

```
sudo [ -d /path/to/my/place -a ! -L /path/to/my/place ] && …
```

You should avoid it though. From [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D):

> The binary `-a` and `-o` […] are XSI extensions to the POSIX standard. All are marked as obsolescent in POSIX-2008. They should not be used in new code. One of the practical problems with `[ A = B -a C = D ]` (or `-o`) is that POSIX does not specify the results of a `test` or `[` command with more than 4 arguments. It probably works in most shells, but you can't count on it. If you have to write for POSIX shells, then you should use two `test` or `[` commands separated by a `&&` operator instead.

So this should be safer if you want to use `[`:

```
sudo [ -d /path/to/my/place ] && sudo [ ! -L /path/to/my/place ] && …
```

Comment: Excellent! `sudo bash -c ...` Worked like a charm. Thanks.